# openvpn client cannot connect via UDP, but TCP works fine

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, openvpn, udp

**problem:**

I've setup a new ubuntu 20 vm on esxi and installed openvpn.  It can connect to multiple vpn servers, like protonvpn, but only through tcp, not udp.

**troubleshooting:**

- Used netcat to verify UDP connectivity to the hosts on their respective ports, no problem there.
- Made sure UFW is completely off and iptables has no rules with a default policy of ACCEPT on all chains.
- tried to verify MTU maximum size by using ping.  local gateway accepts packets up to 65515 bytes.  proton vpn servers only seem to accept packets up to 1480 bytes.

what am I missing here?  I'm 99% sure its something on the client side, but i'm not sure what else to look for that could be causing this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Helps when you allow UDP to the subnet on your network firewall.  I dont quite understand how `pfsense` was allowing `netcat` to work and verify connectivity, but its fixed so I'm happy.